# Hibernate using fully JavaConfig aproach in a Spring Batch Job

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a batch job fully configured using JavaConfig. having difficulties, mainly due to little material I found on configuration using only java. In the spring batch manual itself there is no information on how to fully configure a job with spring batch using only java. I do not know if it's because this configuration model is more recent than the xml based aprouch...

Right now I'm having trouble setting up hibernate using this configuration class. I have an xml settings, but I'm not knowing how to reference it or how to change these settings for a fully "JavaConfig" version.

My job configuration class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class CrawlerBatchConfiguration {


    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs) {
        return jobs.get("myJob").start(flow()).end().build();
    }

    protected Step step0() {
        return steps.get("setupCrawlerStep").tasklet(tasklet()).build();
    }

    private Flow flow() {
        FlowBuilder<Flow> builder = new FlowBuilder<>("flow1");
        builder.start(step0())
                .next(step1())
                .end();
        return builder.build();
    }


    @Bean
    protected Step step1() {
        return steps.get("processProductStep")
                .<TransferObject, Product>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Tasklet tasklet() {
        return new StartCrawlerTasklet();
    }


    @Bean
    protected ProductList getProductList() {
        return new ProductList();
    }

    @Bean
    public CrawlerListener listener() {
        CrawlerListener listener = new RibeiraoListener();
        return listener;
    }


    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<TransferObject, Product> processor() {
        return new ProductProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<TransferObject> reader() {
        return new ProductItemReader();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Product> writer() {
        return new HIbernateProductsItemWriter();
    }


    @Bean
    public Crawler crawler() {
        return new RibeiraoCrawler(new UserAgentFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProductBo productBo() {
        return new ProductBoImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProductDao productDao() {
        return new ProductDaoImpl();
    }
}
```

And the hibernate config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>

            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>br.com.alexpfx.supermarket.domain.Product</value>
                <value>br.com.alexpfx.supermarket.domain.Manufacturer</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: `<prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>` :)

Comment: @v.ladynev I didn't understand. This configuration file is not being read yet since I move to JavaConfig aproach.

Comment: It is just an incorrect property name, nothing more. I think you need to add an example of your JavaConfig.